# Python logging - non-intrusive approach for testing alternative loggers like Twiggy or Loguru?

Tags: python, logging, decoupling

This is **not** a question about recommendations for `logging` alternatives.

However, I would like to try some alternative loggers, like possibly Twiggy or Loguru.  Or something else.  The problem is that, while `logging`'s *configuration* is centralized, *acquisition* of the logger is all over the codebase.

#### aquisition code

```
import logging  # I'd like to import an alternative here.
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
```

#### and how many instances there are

(basically, each `.py` file that uses logging has those 2 lines of code)

```
ack -l --python logging.getLogger | wc -l
193
```

What are some good approaches to bypass stdlib logging behind the scene and return a Loguru or Twiggy logger instead when `logging.getLogger` is called?

I can think of several:

- putting a custom `logging.py` earlier in the Python path entries than the stdlib version
- using an import mock decorator to return a different module than the stdlib
- monkeypatching `logging` by importing it early on and setting `logging.getLogger` to a custom factory function return a Loguru or whatever alternative.
- Customizing [site.py](https://docs.python.org/3/library/site.html), the site initialization module.

Has anybody tried to swap out `logging` without resorting to modifying each and every `logging.getLogging` call?  How did you do it?

Also, this is in the context of a Django web app.  I'd rather not mess with `settings.LOGGING` however.

For reference, this is a Loguru logger acquisition and the type of code I *absolutely* want to avoid distributing over 200+ files before finding out Loguru is not suitable for my needs.

```
from loguru import logger  #❌ I don't want to have to this 200 times!!!

logger.debug("That's it, beautiful and simple logging!")
```

At the end of the day, an ideal situation would be for me to find a good alternative to log with for a while, then perhaps even revert to stdlib `logging` at a later date, if I get its configuration fixed.  That shouldn't require touching all those files however.  And I may try first Loguru, then Twiggy, then something else.

Basically, how do I uncouple the actual provider of the logging functionality from all the application files?

Also, just to be clear, whatever logging provider I use will have to support, or can be adjusted to support, the logger API, like `logger.info(), logger.debug()` etc...  So this question is **not** concerned about application code like:

`logger.info("this is your info")`

Comment: Doing `from loguru import logger` 200 times is just one find/replace, but if you expect to be changing that a lot, make it `from my.loggin.module import logger` instead, so you never have to do it again.

Comment: @zvone replacing `import logging` with `import my.logging.module as logging`  is a possibility.  then `getLogger` could just return Loguru or Twiggy or even stdlib logging when called.  Why don't you put that as an answer?

Comment: Makes sense. Did so :)

Answer (score 1):

Since you plan to change the loggers, it makes sense to first centralise the code, so that it can be changed easily afterwards.

So, you could create a new logging module, which behaves just like the built-in `logging`, and replace all imports with

```
import my.logging.module
```

Then modify `my.logging.module` when you need to implement a different logger.

There, in `my.logging.module` you can choose to implement your own functions with some special logic (switching between different loggers etc), or just do the hacky `from logging import *` for the default behaviour ;)

Comment: I like it, but to truly minimize the impact to the "acquisition code" 
`import my.logging as logging ;`
`logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)`  seems best.  That way I'd have an easy target for a `sed` **import logging** and don't to touch *anything* else.

Answer (score -1):

I used `usercustomize.py` to replace the logger.  That worked, but what didn't work was that celery and django both pretty much freaked out on not seeing the full stdlib `logging` API.

But patching logging worked very well this way, as long as celery and django weren't involved.

#### usercustomize.py:

location **/Users/myuser/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/usercustomize.py**.  Python is very particular about that location, it what you see in

`$ python -m site`

```
USER_SITE: '/Users/myuser/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages'
```

You can just drop a symlink to `usercustomize.py` at that location.  However, this also means that logging is affected for **all** your Python code (though you could use an environment variable to call the original logging.getLogger).

This mostly did what I wanted (the actual code is a bit more complex, but only because loguru didn't like being initialized early on) so I had to use a property.

```
import logging

from loguru import logger

stdlib_getLogger = logging.getLogger

# configuration goes into an endless loop if done "too early"
# and `asyincio needs to be imported first for some reason
# I ended up using a class and @property
# but that has more to do with loguru than the core idea of replacement

# logger.configure(
# handlers=[
#     dict(sink=sys.stderr, format="[{time}] {message}"),
#     dict(sink="mylog.log", enqueue=True, serialize=True),
# ])




def custom_getLogger(name, *args, **kwargs):

    #loguru's
    return logger        

    #if you want to revert to stdlib conditionally
    return stdlib_getLogger(name, *args, **kwargs)

logging.getLogger = custom_getLogger
```